# Rails 3 Overriding Named Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a polymorphic-like association (not a true Rails one) for a Commentable implementation. I'd like to be able to use the same views for all the comments though. For my named routes, I just want to be able to call `edit_comment_path` and have it go to my new method.

My routes will look something like this:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end

resources :pictures do
  resources :comments
end

resources :comments
```

Right now I've overridden `edit_comment_path` in a helper module, but the one generated by `resources :comments` keeps getting called instead. I am keeping the `resources :comments` because I'd like to be able to access the comments directly and some Mixins I have rely on it.

Here is my override method in `module CommentsHelper`:

```
  def edit_comment_path(klass = nil)
    klass = @commentable if klass.nil?
    if klass.nil?
      super
    else
      _method = "edit_#{build_named_route_path(klass)}_comment_path".to_sym
      send _method
    end
```

**EDIT**

```
# take something like [:main_site, @commentable, @whatever] and convert it to "main_site_coupon_whatever"
  def build_named_route_path(args)
    args = [args] if not args.is_a?(Array)
    path = []
    args.each do |arg|
      if arg.is_a?(Symbol)
        path << arg.to_s 
      else
        path << arg.class.name.underscore
      end
    end
    path.join("_")
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, none of this was necessary, the built-in polymorphic_url methods worked just fine:

@commentable is set in a before_filter in CommentsController

```
<%= link_to 'New', new_polymorphic_path([@commentable, Comment.new]) %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_polymorphic_url([@commentable, @comment]) %>

<%= link_to 'Show', polymorphic_path([@commentable, @comment]) %>

<%= link_to 'Back', polymorphic_url([@commentable, 'comments']) %>
```

**EDIT**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true

   validates :body, :presence => true 
end



class CommentsController < BaseController

  before_filter :find_commentable

private 

  def find_commentable
    params.each do |name, value|
      if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
        @commentable = $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
        return @commentable
      end
    end
    nil
  end

end
```

Comment: Heh, thanks for this. I was about to go into that metavortex as well. I couldn't find much about this in the Rails doc -- seems to be kind spread across blogs and such. Any chance you could share your `@commentable` logic? That's pretty interesting

Comment: @Joseph Weissman see my update. Something like this should work. I cut and pasted it from old code though as the question is kind of old.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having trouble trying to over-ride routes with a helper module. Try defining it in your ApplicationController and making it a `helper_method` as well. You could also adjust the name to avoid conflict and have it serve as a wrapper, something like this:

```
helper_method :polymorphic_edit_comment_path
def polymorphic_edit_comment_path(object = nil)
  object ||= @commentable
  if (object)
    send(:"edit_#{object.to_param.underscore}_comment_path")
  else
    edit_comment_path
  end
end
```

Comment: I think the wrapper approach is the best since it makes things more readable. Quick question. I have my own method build_named_route_path(klass) that can take an Array like [:main, @commentable, @object]. There an easier way to parse this using ActiveSupport?

Comment: Also, the method you posted doesn't work. Mine works on all views except the index view. Very strange.